# Python 3 control print output for class

Tags: matrix, python-3.x, operator-overloading

I have a class, Matrix, i would like when print is called on this class, instead of printing

<**main**.Matrix instance at 0x7f41fb17de18>

I would like to be able to control the output something like

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

In C++ i would just overload the << operator.  How can i do this in python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to produce a printable output, implement [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__). You can also implement [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) but is usually used to create a more technical representation instead of just a human-readable output.

```
>>> class MyType:
        def __str__ (self):
            return 'foo'
>>> print(MyType())
foo
```